# Offset value as a variable

Tags: soql, limits, dynamic-soql

I have to put an offset value in a query as a variable.Can someone please help here?Please my code snippet here.

```
Integer lim=101;
for(Integer i=0;;i+lim){
Integer j=i-1;

return Database.getQueryLocator([
        select Id, Name,(select Signature_vod__c
        from Call2_vod__r
        where Signature_Date_vod__c != Null
        and Account_vod__c != null limit 100 offset :j) from Account
        ]);
```

Comment: And what is the problem/error ?

Comment: Keep in mind that offset is limited to 2000, and that should be considered in your code if you want to prevent an exception when crossing 2000.

Comment: Hi SF_USER! Please find the error as below. : Compile Error: SOQL OFFSET clause may not appear in a sub-query where the parent query retrieves more than one record at line 8 column 41

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation said :

> A sub-query can use OFFSET only if the parent query has a LIMIT 1
>   clause. The following query is a valid use of OFFSET in a sub-query:

```
SELECT Name, Id
    (
        SELECT Name FROM Opportunities LIMIT 10 OFFSET 2
    )
FROM Account
ORDER BY Name
LIMIT 1
```

Yo need to add `LIMIT 1` in the parent query.

See http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm

**EDIT :**

Try :

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
        select Id, Name,(select Signature_vod__c
        from Call2_vod__r
        where Signature_Date_vod__c != Null
        and Account_vod__c != null limit 100 offset :j) from Account
        LIMIT 1 // --> Add this
        ]);
```

Comment: HI SF_USER! I have offset value as dynamic one.

Comment: I updated my post. Try the solution please.